# Error with matplotlib.show() : module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a Python 3.6 user and I've been trying to learn how to use the matplotlib and pandas libraries. But as I try to use the "show()" function, I get the following error:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
df=pd.DataFrame({'Day':[1,2,3], 'Revenue':[100,200,320]})
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

***ERROR: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'show'***

Answer (score 104):

Do not use

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

but rather use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

`plt` is an abbreviation for `pyplot`, which is a module inside the `matplotlib` package. You need to address it for the kinds of things you are doing, not just `matplotlib`.

Note that `matplotlib` can be used without using `pyplot` at all, but most people find it easier to use `pyplot`. See [its documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) or [the tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) for details.

Comment: While this answer is of course correct and helpful for the questioner, the whole community would benefit more from having the question marked as duplicate instead of being answered. I would guess that from the type of question and its potential answer one could easily guess that this has already been asked at some point back in time. Quickly looking for a duplicate is then an easy task. If a duplicate question does not have a sufficient answer one may then add one to that question instead of the new one; or at least link to it and only provide specific details here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: 1) What do you suggest I do now? 2) Just how is "Quickly looking for a duplicate" "an easy task"? Is there a good facility in Stack Exchange or do you use a general search engine?

Comment: 1) You don't need to change anything here, my comment is more directed to making you and others aware of the matter and improve handling of future cases, where you can use the "close/duplicate off.." button and/or provide a link as comment. 2) Both, the search field on top of the site as well as any search engine are good choices. In this case googling the error directly gives some potential duplicates.